# Laravel Gazzel Making multiple requests to same URL without login multiple times

Tags: php, xml, laravel-5, xmlhttprequest, guzzle6

So I have this class setup in laravel. It is using following header to initialize requests.

```
    $this->xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
    <query xmlns=\"http://www.someurl.com/queryLanguage/v1.0\">
        <logon>
            <userName>".config('some.username')."</userName>
            <password>".config('some.password')."</password>
            <deviceName>".config('some.device')."</deviceName>
        </logon>";
```

Then I have like 10 requests to make to the same url with above auth details.

so im doing it like.

```
    $xml1 = $this->xml;
    $xml1 .= "some xml";
    $options = [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF8',
        ],
        'body' => $xml1,
    ];

    $client = new Client(); 
    $response = $client->request('POST', config('some.apiurl'), $options);

    $xml2 = $this->xml;
    $xml2 .= "some xml";
    $options = [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF8',
        ],
        'body' => $xml2,
    ];

    $client = new Client(); 
    $response = $client->request('POST', config('some.apiurl'), $options); 

    $xml3 = $this->xml;
    $xml3 .= "some xml";
    $options = [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF8',
        ],
        'body' => $xml3,
    ];

    $client = new Client(); 
    $response = $client->request('POST', config('some.apiurl'), $options);
```

as you can see with each requests it makes a new login and eventually ended up getting too many concurrent logons error from remote server. so my question is how we use this api login information and just login once with guzzel and then use it for multiple requests later.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guzzle CookieJar to save your session and send it to the next request.

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies

```
#Request-1
$login = $client->request("POST" , $url , [
    "headers" => $header,
    "body" => $xmlLogin
]);

// Here you should get all cookies from $login request and save it to $tmpCookieJar variable for example.

// For request-2 it will depends on the requirement of the endpoint or api.

#Request-2
$action2 = $client->request("POST" , $url , [
    "headers" => $header,
    "body" => $xmlLogin, // If necessary
    "cookies" => $tmpCookieJar
]);
```

Comment: can you update this answer with 2 requests so I can understand how to do this. so should I omit xml logon section in the second request?